# z-index not working in IE?

Tags: css

I am creating 1 of those CSS3 ribbons

http://www.jsfiddle.net/G4QQ2/

[image]

It works in FF & Chrome but in IE, the `z-index` does not seem to work

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: I've experimented a bit with your jsfiddle, and my guess is that IE simply doesn't support z-index in combination with the pseudo-element `before`. BTW, I'd avoid negative z-index if possible, because older FF don't support it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RoToRa's comment is correct

> I've experimented a bit with your jsfiddle, and my guess is that IE simply doesn't support z-index in combination with the pseudo-element before. BTW, I'd avoid negative z-index if possible, because older FF don't support it properly

I think a better fix will be from @mercator's comment this post

> Not an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem: jsfiddle.net/G4QQ2/7 I.e. Add border-top: 0 to the h1:before and adjust its top to top: 34px. That way you don't need the z-index at all.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem: http://www.jsfiddle.net/G4QQ2/7/ I.e. Add `border-top: 0` to the `h1:before` and adjust its `top` to `top: 34px`. That way you don't need the `z-index` at all.